# O que são as unidades svh, lvh e dvh do CSS?

Tags: css

Não é difícil encontrarmos elementos do HTML que possuem a propriedade CSS `height: 100vh` para ocupar todo o espaço vertical, mas recentemente cruzei com as unidades `svh`, `lvh` e `dvh`.

**Exemplo usando `100vh`**

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div>Ocupa 100% da tela usando 100vh</div>
```

O que são essas unidades e quais as diferenças delas para a `vh`?

**Exemplos usando `100svh`,  `100lvh`, `100dvh` e `100vh`**

```css
div { width: 20vw; float: left; }

div:nth-child(1) { height: 100svh; background-color: red; }
div:nth-child(2) { height: 100lvh; background-color: blue; }
div:nth-child(3) { height: 100dvh; background-color: green; }
div:nth-child(4) { height: 100vh; background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<div>Ocupa 100% da tela usando 100svh</div>
<div>Ocupa 100% da tela usando 100lvh</div>
<div>Ocupa 100% da tela usando 100dvh</div>
<div>Ocupa 100% da tela usando 100vh</div>
```

Comment: Material que **pode** ser usado como apoio: https://ishadeed.com/article/new-viewport-units/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essa medidas são parte das [unidades relativas ao viewport](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-units), que também inclui o `vh` (também incluso, fora outras unidades descritas no fim do texto) e são usadas para ajustar as propriedades que as usarem conforme o viewport padrão do *user-agent*, que pode variar entre a *viewport pequena*, *viewport larga/grande* e *viewport dinâmica*.

Então o importante é entender o que cada prefixo significa:

| Prefixo | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| `v*` | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport |
| `sv*` | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport pequena |
| `lv*` | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport larga/grande |
| `dv*` | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport dinâmica |

Depois de entender os prefixo segue a explicação de quando (geralmente) ocorre cada viewport:

#### Viewport pequena (small)

Geralmente é o espaçamento **descontado** relativo ao tamanho do viewport de quando a barra de endereços é visível. Costuma ser barra de endereços, mas isso pode variar conforme a implementação do navegador, pode ser que outros elementos UI estejam nesse espaço. O Safari para macOS também possui recurso semelhante, trabalhando com essas medidas.

O ajuste do tipo de viewport geralmente ocorre conforme a rolagem da página, alternando entre ambos tipos.

#### View porte larga/grande (large)

Se refere ao espaço todo, independente da barra de endereços estar visível, então a medida será feita desconsiderando o espaço que a barra de endereços ocupa.

#### Viewport dinâmica (dynamic)

Nesse caso o elemento se ajustará ao viewport dinamicamente, quando a barra de endereços for visível ele se comportará semelhante ao `svh`, quando a barra for retraída ele se comportará semelhante ao `lvh`, nos navegadores mais comuns isso ocorre geralmente conforme o a rolagem da página

> **Nota:** o `dvh` em algumas versões do Safari em macOS existia um bug (que já foi corrigido): https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=242758, se tiver problema pode ser que o seu sistema esteja desatualizado.

### Exemplo do resultado do VH, SVH, LVH e DVH

Com o código a seguir (no StackSnippet não funciona de forma ideal):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  html, body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  body {
    background: #253238;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1vh;
    padding: 1vh;
  }

  .item {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,freesans,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: .2vw .2vw 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    background: #dffbfc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 98vh;
  }

  .lvh {
    background: #c2dfe3;
    height: 98lvh;
  }

  .svh {
    background: #9eb4c1;
    height: 98svh;
  }

  .dvh {
    background: #5c6a73;
    height: 98dvh;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="item vh">VH</div>
  <div class="item lvh">LVH</div>
  <div class="item svh">SVH</div>
  <div class="item dvh">DVH</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A área que o `svh` e `lvh` ocupam:

[image: exemplo VH, SVH, LVH e DVH]

A diferença do `dvh` (o dinâmico) pode ser observado na animação a seguir:

[image: dvh]

Note como se adapta a ambas medidas de viewport

---

Segue outras unidades de medidas com esses prefixos, que trabalham conforme o tipo de viewport:

## Eixo inline da caixa

| Prefixo | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| vi | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport no eixo inline da caixa |
| svi | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport pequena no eixo inline da caixa |
| lvi | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport larga/grande no eixo inline da caixa |
| dvi | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport dinâmica no eixo inline da caixa |

## Eixo block da caixa

| Prefixo | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| vb | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport no eixo block da caixa |
| svb | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport pequena no eixo block da caixa |
| lvb | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport larga/grande no eixo block da caixa |
| dvb | 1% da altura do tamanho da viewport dinâmica no eixo block da caixa |

Também temos as medidas

vmin, svmin, lvmin, dvmin

- Igual ou menor que *vw ou *vh

vmax, svmax, lvmax, dvmax

- Igual ou maior que *vw or *vh

> **Nota:** Assim que possível irei adicionar exemplos para explicar melhor o quando usar essas outras medidas

Comment: Essa resposta foi uma das melhores explicações que já vi sobre esse assunto. Parabéns

Comment: Só a animação já valeu a recompensa. Parabéns! Só senti falta na resposta de ter descrito que a diferença entre as "viewport pequena" e "larga" refere-se ao espaço utilizado pela caixa de endereço da página.

Comment: @Woss adicionei de forma descritiva, assim que possivel faço algumas artes para melhor orientar o texto da publicação.

Answer (score -5):

Em uma tela, o espaço que o navegador (UA) toma é dividido entre o espaço da própria interface do navegador (UA interface) e a área do conteúdo (viewport).

Porém a interface navegadores modernos as vezes mudam de tamanho, principalmente em celulares. Por exemplo, ao arrastar o conteúdo numa direção os menus do navegador desaparecem, aumentando o viewport, e em outra direção os menus do navegador reaparecem, diminuindo o viewport.

A medida `vh`, baseada no tamanho inicial do viewport deixa de ser útil. E a própria alteração do viewport dificulta organizar o seu conteúdo de forma a ocupar múltiplos ou frações exatas do viewport, que não se sabia de antemão.

Por conta disso as variações de medida pequena (`s`mall), grande (`l`arge) e dinâmica (`d`ynamic) da medida `vh` foram criadas, prevendo essa variação do viewport causada exclusivamente pelo navegador.

Assim você pode fixar ou organizar o seu conteúdo prevendo o viewport inicial, maior, menor ou mutante, respectivamente `vh`, `svh`, `lvh` ou `dvh`.

As definições formais você pode ver no [site da w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#viewport-relative-units), e um pouco da história é contada [aqui](https://dev.to/frehner/css-vh-dvh-lvh-svh-and-vw-units-27k4).